Not authorized to use https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares/{postId}
I am experiencing an issue with accessing the LinkedIn API to retrieve metrics for shares. I can successfully create posts using the ugcPosts endpoint,
but when I try to retrieve metrics using the shares endpoint, I receive the following error:
{
"status": 403,
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
"message": "Not enough permissions to access: shares.GET.NO_VERSION"
}
Here are the details of my setup:

API Endpoints: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts (POST), https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares/{postId} (GET)
Scopes: openid, profile, w_member_social
OAuth2 Flow: Authorization code flow
Access Token: Successfully obtained and used for creating posts

Does anybody know the steps to resolve this issue? Are additional scopes or configurations required?
I generated my LinkedIn access token in the LinkedIn Dev portal.
Using that token,
I did a POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts in postman and it worked.
I did a POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts in a C# program and it worked.
Each time, I get the {postId} as a result.
But when I tried https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares/{postId} in postman (with the same access token) it failed.
I didn't try https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares/{postId} in in my C# program (no benefit).
I repeated the same steps by generating my LinkedIn access token in my C# program.
Same results.

You probably have to consult the documentation. It's an authorization issue. But yes, most likely your missing required scopes or LinkedIn do some other check like hypothetically e.g. you have to have some claim premiumUser set. Scopes are not the the only concept on which authorization relies on. It could be other claims and it could also be some custom logic. E. g. in an online shop you could have the scope product.order but they could check that you have unpaid bills and therefore still not allow you to order a product. So long story short, only way to find out is the documentation.

Thanks, I'll double-check the documentation.
You are making a good point on FREE TIER vs PREMIUM TIER for scope on LinkedIn Endpoints.
I know that Twitter has premium subscriptions if you want to use more scope on their API Endpoints.
But I haven't seen anything similar on LinkedIn yet, but there might be something similar.
NoCode products like Make only offer the create linkedin post functions but no read post functions.
Tools like Taplio and Shield must have access to LinkedIn read post functions.
So there is a likelihood of scope restrictions on LinkedIn FREE tier for APIs.

It seems I need r_member_social permission and it seems that permission is granted to select developers only.
